# Understanding Zipf's law calculation for probability of a word

Tags: self-study, distributions, natural-language, zipf

So, I am analyzing a a corpus of ~1,000,000 words and I am trying to understand how I can use Zipf's law. I found on some textbook slides the following formulas:

$$f_r = c/r$$
$$p_r = k/r $$

where $f_r$ is the occurrence of a word at rank $r$, $p_r$ is the probability of the occurrence of a word at rank $r$, $c$ and $k$ are constants.

I got three points, e.g:

$$f_{10}=8800$$
$$f_{100}=930$$
$$f_{1000}=89$$

I succeeded in calculating $c$ by replacing the $f_r$ and the $r$ and then I average the various scores. But, how can I calculate $k$? how do I get $p_r$, is it a safe assumption to just do $f_r/total$ ?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is such of a trivial question, hope someone confirms